# Redirecting a domain to subfolder while keeping the domain name with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, server, dns

I'm new to using and changing the workings of a server and all that.

So far I've only had one server with one domain for myself, but now a business is getting some traction and I want to use a different domain for it while keeping it on my server.

The situation is like this: I have the main domain and root directory like `maindomain.com` and I also just bought `projectdomain.com`.

The files for `projectdomain.com` are within `maindomain.com/project/`.

I have established a forward from `projectdomain.com` to `maindomain.com/project/` already, but I can't access sites via the url.

For example:

I want to type `projectdomain.com/somecontent/` and access `maindomain.com/project/somecontent` while maintaining the `projectdomain.com` link in the address bar (it should read `projectdomain.com/somecontent`).

When I try it now I always end up in `maindomain.com/project/` and never in the file I specified in the url.

I've tried working around it with the .htaccess file, but don't really know much about it. What I have now is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?projectdomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://maindomain.com/project/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Sorry for the noob question, I really don't know much about the topic and I'm not sure what to google to get what I want.

Comment: Remove `R=301`, leave only `[L]`

Comment: thank you, I tried this now and it does seem to let me get to a page like example.com/page/ and not ending at example.com
but it also changes the url in the adress bar. how would I rewrite this?

Comment: If you remove the `R`, apache will not change url in address bar, but maybe your app/site is doing that...